# Container folder modification

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

Using MFC Dialog Box application in VC++,

I have a file path(without the end file) which is displayed in an edit box. This path represents the container folder location for the file:

```
    CString container = myPath.Left(myPath.ReverseFind(_T('\\')));

    m_Container.SetWindowText(container);
```

The variable 'myPath' holds the current directory(full path).

For example, C:\DE1\Progs\Dev\FreeTest\gm.prg

with container displayed as: C:\DE1\Progs\Dev\FreeTest

How can I modify the container folder(i.e. 'FreeTest') only and restrict any changes further up to path within the edit box? Is there a specific function or method to do this

Comment: You should specify which graphical library you are using, because the answer depends on that

Comment: Apologies, I'm using VC++ and writing a MFC Dialog box application. CDialog is the class type and CEdit for the edit box...just updated the question..

Comment: Then you should add the mfc and visual-c++ tags, so that people specializing in that have the question appear on their feed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SpanIncluding(or SpanExcluding) function of CString.
Please check this link
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa300657(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: Thank you Selva...I'll check it out